# How can I filter and count JSON objects latitude and longitude 10km from origin?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to filter and count objects of an api endpoint that are within 10km of the given origin. I keep getting stuck on how to filter the api results and count the number of items that match.

I was able to filter the data and count how many items have a city of "Hong Kong" with a 1-to-1 comparison, but the distance calculation is another complex layer for filtering data.

```
coords = [
   [
      City: "Hong Kong",
      Lat: “22.667790”, 
      Long: “-111.909905” 
   ],
   [
      City: "Atlanta",
      Lat: “22.958769”, 
      Long: “-111.948939”
   ],
   [
      City: "Paris",
      Lat: “23.989803”, 
      Long: “-112.989850”
   ],
   [
      City: "Sydney",
      Lat: “22.001118”,
      Long:”-111.939433”
   ],
   [
      City: "Hong Kong",
      Lat: “22.667790”, 
      Long: “-111.909905” 
   ],
];



origin = [  
     lat:"22.111009",
     long: "-113.667870"
];

function getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
     var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
     var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
     var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
     var a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
     var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
     var d = R * c; // Distance in km
     return d;

}


function deg2rad(deg) {
     return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}



coords.forEach(function(coord){
    distance = getDistance(coord.lat, coord.long, origin.lat, origin.long);

    if (distance < 10){
        return distance;
    }

});
```

So far I have not been able to return anything meaningful, only a list of the distance between the origin and each one of the objects. It should show how many cities are with in 10km of the origin.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `filter` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const filtered = coords.filter(coord => {
    distance = getDistance(coord.lat, coord.long, origin.lat, origin.long);
    return distance < 10
});
```

now you have filtered results stored in the array named `filtered`

Answer (score 0):

To filter your list you can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Your origin, of course, should be less than 10km away and none of your cities matched, see:

```js
var coords = [{
    City: "Hong Kong",
    lat: "22.667790",
    long: "-111.909905"
  },
  {
    City: "Atlanta",
    lat: "22.958769",
    long: "-111.948939"
  },
  {
    City: "Paris",
    lat: "23.989803",
    long: "-112.989850"
  },
  {
    City: "Sydney",
    lat: "22.001118",
    long: "-111.939433"
  },
  {
    City: "Hong Kong",
    lat: "22.667790",
    long: "-111.909905"
  }
];



origin = {
  lat: "22.611009",
  long: "-111.967870"
};

function getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
  var a =
    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;

}


function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}



var matching = coords.filter(function(coord) {
  return getDistance(coord.lat, coord.long, origin.lat, origin.long) < 10;
});

console.info(matching);
```